# Select from a comma separated list within a data-attr

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dynamically filter a list of members who have been 'tagged' with sectors using a  menu and a data-attribute (membersectors) containing the tags.

http://jsfiddle.net/richardblyth/yp8q3ewh/

The problem I am having is with the actual jQuery itself - because the data-membersectors is a comma separated list it does not seem to be selecting.

```
$("#js-select-sector").bind("change", function() {

  console.log((this.value));

  //Show divs with data-attr which contain the selected value
  $("div.member-small[data-membersectors*='(" + this.value + ")']").show();

  //Hide those with data-attr which do not contain the selected value
  $("div.member-small:not([data-membersectors*='(" + this.value + ")'])").hide();

});
```

When the user selects a sector from the  menu, it should hide all  which do not contain that 'tag'/sector (inside their data-membersectors)

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are the parentheses around `this.value`? This code works:

```
$("#js-select-sector").bind("change", function() {
    //Show divs with data-attr which contain the selected value
    $("div.member-small[data-membersectors*='" + this.value + "']").show();

    //Hide those with data-attr which do not contain the selected value
    $("div.member-small:not([data-membersectors*='" + this.value + "'])").hide();
});
```

Comment: Ugh! Sometimes you stare at the same bit of code for so long and fail to see the obvious! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the brackets around the attribute value in the selector:

```
$("#js-select-sector").bind("change", function() {
    $("div.member-small").hide();
    $("div.member-small[data-membersectors*='" + this.value + "']").show();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yp8q3ewh/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Or ...you can use .filter() like:

```js
$("#js-select-sector").bind("change", function() {
  var val = this.value;
  $("div.member-small").filter(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-membersectors").indexOf(val) != -1 ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Select</h1>

<select id="js-select-sector">
  <option selected="selected">Select a sector</option>
  <option value="sector1">Sector 1</option>
  <option value="sector2">Sector 2</option>
  <option value="sector3">Sector 3</option>
</select>

<h2>Results</h2>

<div class="member-small" data-membersectors="sector1">Member A</div>
<div class="member-small" data-membersectors="sector2, sector3">Member B</div>
<div class="member-small" data-membersectors="sector1, sector3">Member C</div>
<div class="member-small" data-membersectors="sector3">Member D</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wc1k82hw/